Notepad++ default instance to open new files
I usually have two windows (instances) of notepad++, each one with specific tabs. One is for personal things, the other for work.
I want notepad++ to open new files in the "work" window by default. But I can't find anything like this in settings, although it exists a multi instance preferences tab... how can I do?

Seems to be a feature request, see: FAQ: Feature Request or Bug Report

There is no "good" solution yet.
You can try this as alternative, but I do not recommend it:
Create two separate shortcuts for each instance, specifying which window you want new files to open in.
Right-click the shortcut and select Properties. In the Target field, add the command line option -multiInst -nosession -notabbar -nX, where X is the instance number.
Use -n2 for your work instance.
Use -n1 for your Personal instance.
Your Target field might look like this: "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" -multiInst -nosession -notabbar -n2.
When you open Notepad++ using the respective shortcuts, new files should open in the designated instance.
